# Change number of labels on ggplot2 graphic in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display data over some years and my labels on the x axis overlap each other.
[image: overlapping data]

I generate the plot as follows

```
plotData<-subset(myData,myData$category=="value")

test <- ggplot(plotData, aes(x=date, y=value, group=name))
test + geom_line(aes(color=name))
```

if I add

```
 + theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=45))
```

it is slightly better, but still very crowded.

[image: rotated still overlapping data]

Is there any option to specify how many labels there should be per axis, or an option just to display every 10th label?

Comment: Personally I also usetheme_set(theme_classic()), might add some visibility to your graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale_x_date()` with the `date_breaks` argument. An example with some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 1000), y = rep(1:10, each = 100))

df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x, y)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "26 weeks")
```

[image]